# Pass block of statements as argument to the function call

Tags: c++

Consider the following example:

```cpp
func(cond, block_A, block_B) {
    if(cond) {
        block_A; // Run all the statements in the block A
    } else {
        block_B; // Run all the statements in the block B
    }
}

int main() {
    block_A = {
        y = 1;
        std::cout << (y);
        // statement continues ...
    }
    block_B = {
        z = 1;
        std::cout << (z);
        // statement continues ...
    }

    func(true, block_A, block_C);
}
```

Is there any way to pass a block of statements as an argument to the function call?

Comment: This is not how C++ works. `block_A` doesn't have any type. Refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You can put those blocks in a function and then pass a pointer to that function.

Comment: You can pass them as `std::function` which will invoke whatever sequence you want

Comment: How about [*lambda* expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass callables to `func` and use lambda expressions:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename F,typename G>
void func(bool cond, F a, G b) {
    if(cond) {
        a(); // Run all the statements in the block A
    } else {
        b(); // Run all the statements in the block B
    }
}

int main() {
    auto block_A = [](){
        int y = 1;
        std::cout << y;
    };
    auto block_B = [](){
        int z = 1;
        std::cout << z;
    };

    func(true, block_A, block_B);
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you. But I have a doubt, how do I initialize the variable `y` in the `main()` scope, use the `y` value and store some other value in `y` inside the `block_A` scope and retrieve the value in the `main()` scope.

Comment: @Addiction99 read about lambdas and captures

Comment: @Addiction99 fwiw, I rejected your edit because it doesnt match what you ask for in the question. In the question you ask for executing the whole block inside `func`. In your edit you moved part of the block out, this wasnt asked for in the question. When I have time I might add what you suggested as edit as additional information.

Comment: The changes which I added to the edit were the ones that I was looking for. Please add the addition information. That would be very helpful.Thank you

Comment: @Addiction99 sorry, but I dont understand. Is the answer not answering your question? It does execute the two blocks you named `block_A` and `block_B` in `func`